# Reordering array of objects into nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I reorder an array of objects

```
[ {"2007": rank, "2008": rank, "Class": "label 1"}, 
  {"2007": rank, "2008": rank, "Class": "label 2"}, ... ]
```

into a nested object such as:

```
 {"2007": 
      {"label 1": rank, "label 2": rank}, 
 "2008": 
      {"label 1": rank, "label 2": rank}, ...}
```

Comment: I might just be tired but I'm having trouble building a relationship between your two samples that makes sense.

Comment: Can you describe the algorithm somehow (using any paradigm)? It's not clear what you want.

Comment: To the upvoter: would _you_ please explain _us_ the question? _We_ have no idea what's it asking (I do have an idea, but it's really not clear what the asker wants).

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm a social scientist new to js so apologies in advance. I've got script that takes the latter nested object as input but the data in the former. Yearly ranks for a given class vs. All classes and ranks in given year. Sorry to lack specificity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your requirement is to transpose the table and index by `Class`:

- call the input "table"
- call every element of the array "row"
- for every `year` that is a key in at least one row, except the key `Class`

  - make `year` a key in `output`, mapping to the object:

    - each key in `output[year]` is the value `class` of `Class` in some row, mapping to the value:

      - `output[year][class]` = `input.find("Class",class)[year]`

This is one possible implementation:

```
 var input = [ {"2007": rank, "2008": rank, "Class": "label 1"}, 
               {"2007": rank, "2008": rank, "Class": "label 2"} ]
 //////////
 var yr, i;
 var output = {};
 for(i=0; i<input.length; i++){
   var row = input[i];
   for(yr in row){
     output[yr] = output[yr] || {};
     output[yr][row.Class] = row[yr];
   }
 }
 //////////////
 return output;
```

test: http://jsfiddle.net/aT5YG/1

If multiple rows have the same `Class`, the later rows overwrite the previous rows. If the nput was jagged, the output will be jagged.