# Reordering objects in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json object that looks something like:

```
{
    posts: [
        {id: 56, title: 'something', date: '10-10-10 00:00:00'},
        {id: 57, title: 'Apples', date: '10-10-16 00:00:00'},
    ]
}
```

And I am trying to learn how to manipulate data structures in Javascript. I would like to use jquery to reorder these based on the `posts` attributes, so you might reorder based on date, title or id (default is id).

How ever being a novice, I have no idea where to start I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007991/reordering-array-of-objects-into-nested-objects) andI dont think its the direction I want to go.

**Would** the resulting out put be in the same structure? How could I create a collections of models based off this kind of "re-ordering".

The idea is to allow for editing and publishing of one model in a collection, based off the attribute used to re-order or "sort" the collection, thus allowing for faster processing - so I don't always have to pass the whole collection to the server when I really just want to update one model in the collection.

Comment: As the structure you want is an object with keys, it can't really be sorted as there is no order in objects.

Comment: Updated the question to add more options for answers @adeneo

Comment: Do you want to just sort the `posts` array? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript).

Comment: @Blazemonger No this would be a general thing where you pass in the "key" whos resulting value you wanted sorted and the second option would be "sort by what" - where it would check if that attribute exists before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JavaScript [array.sort](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays#sort) method. It may do what you want.

```
var posts = [{"id": 57, "title": "something"}, {"id": 56, "title": "something else"}];
posts.sort(function(a, b) { if (a.id < b.id) { return -1; } else { return 1; } });
for (var i=0; i<posts.length-1; i++) {
    console.log(posts[i].title);
}
// prints "something else" followed by "something"
```

The `sort` method takes a function which is passed two elements, `a` and `b`, and you can return -1 if a is less than b, 0 if they are equal, and 1 if a is greater than b.

Note that my `posts` variable above is just a simplified version of what would be `o.posts` if your described JSON was stored at `o`. Also note that `sort` sorts in place, meaning it will change the array it operates over.